# How do I plot the python output data in 3D with realtime update?

Tags: python-2.7, 3d, plot, vpython

I'm new to python and I coded a program with tons of 5 sets of 3 coordinates (5*3 lists). I wanted to track the position of the five points and hope it can update instantly while the program is running (if not that's fine). Since there are so many data (over 100000 sets), it is inconvenient to output and plot by matlab.
I downloaded VPython module but I cannot plot in 3d. I found VPython really convenient but my program involves complicated calculations so that loops can reduce many lines.

Sorry for a long question, but in short, I wanted a module or something can visualize output of my data in 3d and update from time to time. Thanks.
Python version: 2.7

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to plot things in VPython. This page gives an overview of how to do that: 
http://www.vpython.org/webdoc/visual/graph.html

As for the magnitude of points you are dealing with, you can have some counter that counts to, say, 50, then plots a point and resets itself. So it will plot only 1 out of 50 points, thus not causing a burden on the program.

```
counter = 0
for/while ... :
    counter += 1
    if counter == 50:
         plot(point)
         counter = 0
    ...
```

Comment: VPython is a buggy and dead project. I can't even get it to run on Ubuntu 16. The last updates for it were nearly [5 years ago.](https://github.com/vpython/visual)